# Monolog add additional data at the end when something is logged

Tags: php, monolog

Coming from Yii2 at the end of each request when something is logged, Yii2 adds additional data to your log, for example the `$_POST` data so you know what paramaters caused the issue.
Is there a way to add these information in [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) too?

I don't want to use a [Processor](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Processor/WebProcessor.php) as it includes all those parameters to each and every record. I would just like to add an additional string in case something is logged at the end of the log after all messages are included/send (for example via `BufferHandler` when sending Mails via `SwiftMailerHandler`)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way..
I can extend the default `HtmlFormatter` or `LineFormatter` and include my custom information that way

```
namespace modules\myspa\monolog;

class HtmlFormatter extends \Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter
{
    public function formatBatch(array $records): string
    {
        $formatBatch = parent::formatBatch($records);
        $formatBatch .= '<br><br>Foobar.. add some custom info';
        
        return $formatBatch;
    }
}
```

Then I can add this one as a formatter

```
$swiftMailHandler = new SwiftMailerHandler($swiftMailer, $message, \Monolog\Logger::ERROR);

// add my formatter
$swiftMailHandler->setFormatter(new HtmlFormatter());

$psrLogger->pushHandler(new BufferHandler($swiftMailHandler));
```